# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning while using findOne() in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project in which, at a moment, have to redirect the user if the id of a course does not exist.
This is the code:

```js
router.get('/taller/:id', (req, res) => {
  let tallerId = req.params.id;
  Taller.findOne({_id: tallerId}).then(taller => {
    if(taller) {
      res.render('taller');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
  });
});
```

The idea is that if the id passed in the params actually exists in the Talleres collection, the taller view is rendered. But, if it isn't, then the user should be redirected to the dashboard.

When the code with an invalid id runs I get:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5c7d9da0567a653a40295bc}" at path "_id" for model "Taller"

Thanks in advance for any help.
Tom.

Comment: What is it that you are wanting to happen, or expect to happen? You are telling us the issue you are getting, but not what your expected behavior is.

Comment: @jamesemanon there I updated it!

Comment: are you able to render taller when you have data?

Answer (score 0):

You did not define the catch block so the rejections  i.e errors are not handled try below code

```js
router.get('/taller/:id', (req, res) => {
  let tallerId = req.params.id;
  Taller.findOne({_id: tallerId}).then(taller => {
    if(taller) {
      res.render('taller');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/dashboard')
    }
  });
}).catch(err=>{console.log(err)});
```

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't actually redirect me when no taller is found.

Comment: as you will get the array as result from query, can you please try condition as if(taller.length!=0) instead of if(taller) once